# How to save sorted files in a separate directory?

Tags: text-processing, ls

I have a folder named baypass which contains 2181 files, looks like this (just a few files as an example):

```
anacovis2_210_summary_betai_reg.out_new
anacovis2_2110_summary_betai_reg.out_new
anacovis2_2111_summary_betai_reg.out_new
anacovis2_2112_summary_betai_reg.out_new
```

I want to have all of them sorted, so I used

```
ls -v -1
```

which did the sorting job for me, but I want to have these sorted files saved in a directory. So when I type "ls -v -1" files become sorted but if I type pwd  or ls or any other command they will be unsorted again.
So how can I save the sorted files?
I want to have them sorted and saved to be able to merge them. The order of files are very important.

Comment: it sounds like you would be helped by *renaming* the files such that "anacovis2_210" became "anacovis2_0210", at which point it would sort "naturally" with ls. Are you open to that idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the command you need finally if your goal is merging these files in numerical order. Use [shell brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

```
cat anacovis2_{1..2181}_summary_betai_reg.out_new >> one_file
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Afshin. I got my desired output.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`, you'd do:

```
files=(*.out_new(n))
```

`(n)` being a glob qualifier that causes the glob to be sorted numerically (can also be toggled globally for all globs with `set -o numericglobsort`).

And then:

```
do-something-with $files
```

In `bash`, `ksh93` or `mksh` (or `zsh`) you can store the files as listed by that GNU `ls` in an array with:

```
eval "list=($(ls -v --quoting-style=shell-always))"
do-something-with "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alias:

```
alias ls='ls -1v'
```

Comment: Thanks @abitmol, well yes I get the them sorted and saved but when I run cat command "cat *>covariable1" it merges files based on unsorted order.